# How can i set variable path at dyrectory.exist method at vb.net

Tags: vb.net, path, directory, config

At vb.net project I use the method to determine folder existence at loading form:

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\photo\") = False Then
```

(then: if the folder "photo" doesn't exist, the form show a folderbrowserdialog and a new photo-folder must be selected by the user and that works fine, the choosen path becomes written into a label, but i want to change the initial path (later i want to set externally, maybe reading from config-text file or some flexible variable path like that) i dont know how to modify the: 
*Application.StartupPath & "\photo\"* part of the method
i've tried:

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(label2.text) = False Then
```

adding *Application.StartupPath & "\photo\"* as text and also as tag property for the *label2* but don't works!! :(

Note: as text, the label2 dont show the *&* symbol instead *_*
i think maybe thats the problem...
any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way to do this is to create an setting within the application. Like this.

In the solution explorer, right-click on your solution name. In the context menu, at the bottom, click on `Properties`. This will open up a new tab.

On the left hand side of the new window, you'll see a list of categories. Click on`Settings`

In the main part you will now see a table of rows and columns. There may be only one row, but that's fine. Locate the row that has an asterisk next to it and click on the cell in the name column.

Now you can type the name of the setting you want to create. To match up with the code below, type `defaultPhotoPath`.

When you've done that, click on the next cell and choose the datatype that you want it to contain. For your purposes, you will want to choose `String`. At this point, don't add a value, we'll use some code to do that.

Close the `Properties` tab.

Click on the `Build` menu and choose rebuild

Ok. Halfway there.

In your program, you'll need code that checks that setting we've created and if it's empty, find the right folder, and change the setting to the correct folder.

```
Private Sub GetDefaultPhotoPath()
    If My.Settings.defaultPhotoPath = "" Then
        defaultPhotoPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "photo")
        If Not Directory.Exists(defaultPhotoPath) Then
            Dim newDefaultDirectory As String = "get your correct directory path here"
            defaultPhotoPath = Path.Combine(newDefaultDirectory, "photo")
            My.Settings.defaultPhotoPath = newDefaultDirectory
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So. What this does is to check the value of the setting that we created, and if it hasn't been set, check if the "photo" directory is in the aplication folder. If not, then you should use the code you have to pick the directory and assign it to `newDefaultDirectory`

Finally, it saves thee value to the settings property. Next time it is run, it should find the correct folder without any interaction.

Comment: Vb say:  'defaultphotopath' is not declared. it maybe inaccessible due to its protection level.
same for "path" & "directory"

Comment: ah sorry, I forgot to add that you should create a form level variable as well. So at the top of your form class where you declare your variables, just declare a string type with that name

Comment: `Dim defaultphotopath As String`
   ` Dim path As String`
  `  Dim directory As String`

erro:
`combine is not a member of string`
`edit is not a member of string`

Comment: No .. you don't need to declare Path as a String - It is a .net function already in the System.IO library. If you are already using the path variable for something else, edit the line containing Path.Combine so that it matches this. .. `defaultPhotoPath = system.IO.Path.Combine(newDefaultDirectory, "photo")`

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the `edit is not a member of string` from though. Is it in another part of your code?

Comment: 1drv.ms/f/s!AlqVaIM2GTrSlTmW9VKyqG1KzOoE